# Why are integers in my array turning to 0?

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

Basically I am trying to write a program that asks the user for a number that will determine the length of an array, then asking them for another number that that turns the corresponding value in the cell to 0. However when I tired to printout my array all cells are 0.

I don't think it has to do with the

```
System.out.println (Arrays.toString(NumBox));
```

line since I tired to print out the cells one by one and they still returned zeros.

The code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Game
  {
      public static void main(String []args)
       {
           int StartNum = 0;
           Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
           System.out.println ("How many number would you like to play with?"); 
           StartNum = scan.nextInt();
           int score1 = 0;
           int score2 = 0;



           int[] NumBox = new int[StartNum];
           for (int i = 1; i < NumBox.length+1; i++)
            {
            }



            int pick = 0;
            boolean GG = false;
            System.out.println ("Playing with " + StartNum + "numbers");
            System.out.println ("Notice that 0 represnts an unavailable numbers");
            for (int i = 1; i < NumBox.length+1; i++)
              {
               System.out.println(i);
              }

           while (GG == false)
            {

              System.out.println ("Pick an an available number: ");
              pick = scan.nextInt(); 
              if (pick != 0)
              { 
                score1 = pick + score1;
                NumBox[pick-1] = 0;
                System.out.println (Arrays.toString(NumBox));




             }
             else 
             {
               System.out.println ("Invalid Number");  
                }

            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: What's up with the empty for loop under where you declare `NumBox`?

Comment: when an `int` is declared, it is initialized to zero (by default) - an array of `ints` would behave like that too

Comment: Your ints are **NOT** "_turning into_" zeroes... They start out as zeroes and you never re-assign any of them. Why would you expect them to be any thing else?

Answer (score 2):

From scanning through your code, the array is initialized, which sets the value to 0, but after that the values inside the array are never set to anything else..

Answer (score 2):

You never fill in the array with values. So, in Java they are all set to 0 in the beginning.

Seems like you need to use that empty loop to fill in the array, which by the way would probably look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumBox.length; i++)
```

As arrays in Java ar zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumBox[pick-1] = 0;
System.out.println (Arrays.toString(NumBox));
```

You are constantly setting the value back to 0.
The `forloop` before, the one that prints the values using `System.out.println(i)` is printing 0's because you never initialized any values after creating the array. (no values are initialized until you're in the infinite while loop)

```
       Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); 
       System.out.println ("How many number would you like to play with?"); 
       int StartNum = scan.nextInt(); //receive input
       int score1 = 0;
       int score2 = 0;

       int[] NumBox = new int[StartNum]; //create array length of input
       for (int i = 1; i < NumBox.length+1; i++) {
           //?
       }

        int pick = 0;
        boolean GG = false;
        System.out.println ("Playing with " + StartNum + "numbers"); //prints input number
        System.out.println ("Notice that 0 represnts an unavailable numbers");
        for (int i = 1; i < NumBox.length+1; i++) //prints all the values that havent been initialized yet
          {
           System.out.println(i); //prints all values in array (none have been set yet, 0s)
          }

       while (GG == false)
        {

          System.out.println ("Pick an an available number: ");
          pick = scan.nextInt(); //receives next input
          if (pick != 0)
          { 
            score1 = pick + score1;
            NumBox[pick-1] = 0; //sets a value to 0. the only time a value is set for array
            System.out.println (Arrays.toString(NumBox)); //prints all the 0s
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't initialize an int variable, it will get set to zero.

Your code creates a new int array containing all zeroes.

From that point forward, you never set the value of any array  to anything but zero.

For some reason you have a variable named `score1` that is never used.

Your while loop will also run forever because `GC` is never set to `true`...

Also, why do you have an empty for loop that does nothing?

Time to read your own code and think about what each line does...

Answer (score 0):

So, you have no means to exit the loop, if they don't enter a number your program will crash, and I have no idea what you're doing with scoring. However, this will fix a lot of your other problems.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Game {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int startNum = 0; //start variable and method names with a lower case
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many number would you like to play with?");
        startNum = scan.nextInt();
        int score1 = 0;

        int[] numBox = new int[startNum];
        for (int i = 0; i < numBox.length; i++) {
            numBox[i] = i+1; //initialize your numbers to not be 0- this was your main problem
        }

        int pick = 0;
        boolean GG = false;
        System.out.println("Playing with " + startNum + "numbers");
        System.out.println("Notice that 0 represnts an unavailable numbers");

        while (GG == false) { //GG never changes, so THEY MUST PLAY FOREVER!
            System.out.println("Pick an an available number: ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numBox)); //moved this up here so it is more obvious what they can pick
            pick = scan.nextInt();
            if (pick > 0 && pick <= startNum) {//this will make sure they are in the index range- doesn't account for it not being a number, though... you need a try catch block for that
                score1 = pick + score1; //...no idea what you're doing here
                numBox[pick-1] = 0; //indexing is one below values
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Number");
            }
        }
        scan.close(); //gotta close dat scanner
    }
}
```